# What conclusions can be made if an Ito process is differentiable?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Assume there is an $m$-dimensional Brownian motion $(W_t)_{0\le t\le T}$ and a  square-integrable, progressively measurable $\mathbb R^{1,m}$-valued stochastic process $(Z_t)_{0 \le t \le T}$ (not necessarily continuous) and we know that the function

$$t \mapsto \int_0^t Z_s \mathrm d W_s$$

is almost surely pathwise continuously differentiable in the classical sense.

Can we then say anything restrictive about $Z$, e.g. that it is equal to $0$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If the function $t \mapsto \int_0^t Z_s \, dW_s$ is (pathwise) of bounded variation, then $Z=0$ up to a null set. This follows from the fact that the only continuous martingales with sample paths of bounded variation are the trivial ones.

Comment: @saz , and what if $t \mapsto \int_0^t Z_s dW_s$ is not a martingale, but only a local martingale?